# Excel: Re-position data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a compilation of customer list that I would like to format it into a excel table format. As seen in the image above, is there a way to pull the data from the customer list and insert it into the table?
I can't do it manually because there're too many customers.

Are there any add ons, functions or formula that can do that?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Generally you will get a much better response if you try yourself and post your code if you are struggling. In short there is a fairly easy way to do it using VBA, have you used VBA before?

Comment: Hi Simon. Sad to say I'm not familiar with VBA. Do you have a sample code that I can trial and error?

Comment: This site is for helping people to solve their programming problems, not to provide complete solutions.  If you are not prepared to at least _try_ some code for yourself, you are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are completely new to VBA I'll give you a leg up this time but normally you will need to show what you have done yourself first to get any assistance.

Quick intro to VBA; bring up the VBE (Visual Basic Editor) by pressing Alt + F11, go to Insert and click Module. Paste in the below code and then modify it, adding the remaining data points and working out the row/ column offsets. You can run the code by pressing F5.

```
Sub RePosition()

Dim rng As Range, c As Range, dest As Range

' Set the range to look in for "CustomerNo:"
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
' Set the cell where you want to start putting you re-positioned data
Set dest = Range("I2")

' Loop through each cell in you range
For Each c In rng
    ' If the cell = "CustomerNo:" we know it is a new set
    '  of data
    If c.Value = "CustomerNo:" Then
        ' Based from the cell containing "CustomerNo:" we can
        '  pick up each data point by offsetting row and column
        '  and place it in our destination cell (offsetting dest
        '  as well)
        c.Offset(0, 1).Copy dest
        c.Offset(1, 1).Copy dest.Offset(0, 1)
        c.Offset(2, 1).Copy dest.Offset(0, 2)
        c.Offset(2, 3).Copy dest.Offset(0, 3)
        ' etc for each of the data points


        ' Set the dest to the row below
        Set dest = dest.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

This should get you started, give you an idea of how to approach it, if you run it as is you should get the customer, company, name and address pulled through, you should be able to figure the rest out for yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! Managed to use your code and edit it to my requirement. It's working perfectly!